# ReCharts vertical axis single title but multiple data

Tags: reactjs, charts, recharts

I am attempting to create a barchart in rechart like below, where there is a single title on the left side and a multiple data as a vertical bar but cannot seems to get it to work.

[image]

Here is my code so far

```
const data  = [
    {
      name: "No. of times met",
      value: 50,
      client: "John",
      color1: "#7FD33F",
    },
  ];

 <ResponsiveContainer minWidth={500} width="95%" height={360}>
        <BarChart
          layout="vertical"
          data={data}
          margin={{
            top: 30,
            right: 15,
            bottom: 20,
            left: 60,
          }}
        >
          <CartesianGrid stroke="#f5f5f5" />
          <XAxis type="number" />
          <YAxis dataKey="name" type="category" />
          <Tooltip />

          <Bar dataKey="value" stackId="a">
            {data.map((entry, index) => (
              <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={entry.color1} />
            ))}
          </Bar>
          
        </BarChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
```

this is the output

[image]

My goal is to have display the names when i hover on the chart example if i hover to 7 it will display all the names of the clients. so the raw data is like this.

```
 const data  = [
    {
      name: "No. of times met",
      value: 50,
      client: "John, Mark, Ben, Bob",
      color1: "#7FD33F",
    },
  ];
```